# Postgres server password reset not working

Tags: postgresql

I have Postgresql server 8.2 running on a Windows server. I am trying to reset the root postgres account password and just not having any luck. I have so far done the following:

Edited pg_hba.conf to allow:

```
 local  all   all   trust
```

I then restarted the postgres server so changes could be applied.

Then I opened command prompt and change directory to the bin folder of the postgres installation folder that has all the postgres .exe files.

From what I understand I am supposed to type the following:

```
psql -U postgres
```

And at this point it should let me in and should type:

```
 ALTER USER postgres with password 'newpassword';
```

However, it keeps prompting me for password for user postgres:

And it just does not seem to be working. So from my understanding it seems that the the trust local rule in the pg_hba.conf is not really working correctly.

### Update

My pg_hba.conf file only has the following uncommented tags in it:

```
host  all  all  127.0.0.1/32  trust
local  all   all   trust
host  all  all  ::1/128  md5
```

Comment: Please show us the **complete**  `pg_hba.conf` file. Did you `commit` the `alter user` statement? Plus: you do not have a `;` at the end of the `alter table` statement which would mean the statement was never executed in `psql`. Also: Postgres 8.2 is completely outdated. You should upgrade to a supported version **now**.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i've updated above to show my pg_hba.conf file. it only has those 3 lines uncommented, everything else is just the notes from the default installation which is commented out with #. And in regards to the alter statement, it does not allow me to go that far as when i type psql -U postgres it asks me for password and i cannot get any further. Also from what i've read, the local only works with linux. so what is windows equivalent?

Comment: it seems i can connect if i type psql -h 127.0.0.1 but the problem is none of the users include postgres seem to work, it all returns errors saying role "postgres" does not exist. I cannot create the postgres role because then it also says the user I am trying to create the role under doesnt exist. Any ideas how i can solve this?

Comment: [Start the server in single user mode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-postgres.html) and run `SELECT rolname, rolsuper` to find out how your superuser is called.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking to change the user on the operating system password. The Postgres user is a user on the the operating system.

Plus you are locked out due to the security hierarchy in Host Based Authentication (HBA)

```
host  all  all  127.0.0.1/32  trust
local  all   all   trust
-> host  all  all  ::1/128  md5 <-
```

> NB Loopback Address - ::1/128
>   ::1/128 is the loopback address of the local host which is the equivalent of the 127.0.0.1 in IPv4.

If the postgres user password (as in operating system user) is not set, the postgresq user password is stored

```
%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf
```

Ref [Location of postgresql default user password if not set](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html)

> On Unix systems, the permissions on .pgpass must disallow any access to world or group; achieve this by the command chmod 0600 ~/.pgpass. If the permissions are less strict than this, the file will be ignored. On Microsoft Windows, it is assumed that the file is stored in a directory that is secure, so no special permissions check is made.

You could update you Host Based Authentication (HBA) file and if you wanted to; change the password for the postgres user on the **operating system or windows** Then everything should be fine from **psql**

Hope this helps